# Bootstrap tabs with runat server is not working in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt_hotel_rooms" OnItemDataBound="rpt_hotel_rooms_ItemDataBound" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs item">
            <li id="royal_tab" runat="server" class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#royal">ROYAL</a></li>
            <li id="splendid_tab" runat="server"><a id="spl" data-toggle="tab" href="#splendid">SPLENDID</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="royal" runat="server" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                <%# Eval("hotel_royal") %>
            </div>
            <div id="splendid" runat="server" class="tab-pane fade">
                <%# Eval("hotel_splendid") %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

When i remove the runat server attr of div id=royal and id=splendid then  the code will work properly but when i add runat server attr after that bootstrap tabs not working.

i want hide that div when i need. thats why i am adding runat server to manage both div from code-behind.

What should i do?

if there is a another way to repeater inner div's without adding runat server then tell me please.

Thank you in advance... :)

Comment: The id's are renamed by aspnet to avoid duplicates if you add `runat=server`. But if you do not and there are more than one item in your repeater you will get duplicate id's.

Comment: if i want to access id=royal div without adding  runat server then what should i do?

Comment: This is webforms code and has nothing to do with asp.net-mvc

Comment: Reprogram the tabs module so it can find the renamed id's. Check the html and see what aspnet does to `royal` and `splendid`

Answer (score 0):

Better way if you can do div hide in client side, depend on the condition you want to hide it.can write onclick event there and can write a javascript function to hide or display div. Try once.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `<div>` use `<asp:panel>` with `ClientIDMode="Static"`

`<asp:Panel ID="royal" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" CssClass="tab-pane fade in active">
    <%# Eval("hotel_royal") %>
</asp:Panel>`